# How to get triangle meshes of objects defined in an X3D file?

Tags: mesh, x3d

We can do things rather declaratively in X3D, like saying there is a box in what position and size:

```
<Shape>
  <Box size='1 2 3'/>
  <Appearance>
    <Material/>
  </Appearance>
</Shape>
```

I'd like to know is there any tool that can convert an X3D object to its triangular mesh representation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Install the InstantReality package from instantreality.org

B) Look for the 'aopt' command line tool (depends on your platform)

C) aopt -i foo.x3d -e foo.wrl (exports the rendergraph to a VRML/WRL file)